# Does anyone know what is wrong with my formula in cell E17?

Tags: excel, function, formula

[image]

The code could not work well. I do not understand what the mistake is. I wrote a formula in cell E17 and dragged it down to E22, but the formula does not work at all.

Comment: Please post an example or screenshot of your sheet and the exact error.

Comment: I have posted the screenchot of my my sheet, sir. Could you please look through at it?

Comment: Where `range_lookup` is omitted, column 1 of your table must be sorted.  Either specify that criteria as `FALSE`, or sort your table

Answer (score 2):

Use the forth criterion,  Also use MATCH instead of the nested if.

```
=VLOOKUP(C17,$B$4:$G$7,MATCH(D17,$B$3:$G$3,0),FALSE)
```